# Automapper unsupported mapping int16 to enum

Tags: c#, automapper

- AutoMapper 4.1.1

Source Object:

```
public class Platform_ContentTemplatesModel : OzEfEntity, IEntity<int>
{
    public string TemplateContent { get; set; } 
    public int TemplateIdentifier { get; set; } 
    public short WebsitePropertyId { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; } 
}
```

Destination object:

```
public class OzCpPlatformContentTemplateItemRecord
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TemplateContent { get; set; }
    public ContentTemplateIdentifierEnum TemplateIdentifier { get; set; }
    public WebsitePropertyEnum WebsiteProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping configuraton:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Platform_ContentTemplatesModel, OzCpPlatformContentTemplateItemRecord>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.WebsiteProperty, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.WebsitePropertyId));
```

Now the mapping of TemplateIdentifier from an **int** to the **enum** works perfectly. However the mapping of WebsitePropertyid to WebsiteProperty, namely a **short** to an **enum** fails with the following exception:

> {"Missing type map configuration or unsupported
>   mapping.
>   Mapping types:
>   Int16 -> WebsitePropertyEnum
>   System.Int16 -> WebsitePropertyEnum
>   Destination path: 
>   OzCpPlatformContentTemplateItemRecord.WebsiteProperty.WebsiteProperty
>   Source value:1"}

Now I have an enum member with the value of 1. So is the issue here that the underlying type is a **short**. I cannot change this to an **int** so how do I work around this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure that your destination enum maps to a short

```
public enum WebsitePropertyEnum : short
{
    thing1 = 0,
    thing2 = 1
}
```

Comment: Legend!! That does the trick. Any documentation on the fact that an enum can decend from another type?

Comment: check microsofts enum C# page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx

"The approved types for an enum are byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, or ulong."